# Ring of continuous functions is integral over a subring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is the ring of all continuous functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ integral over the subring of functions $f$ such that $f(1,0) = f(0,1)$?

Comment: Do you mean an integral domain or integrally closed?  I'm assuming an integral domain.  In this case, try to multiply functions which are zero on large regions of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  I.e., $f$ is a function which is zero when $x+y\leq 1$ and $g$ is a function which is zero when $x+y\geq 1$.

Comment: Integrally closed.

Comment: Oh sorry, i mean 'integral over';)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. We have $f^2-(g_1+g_2)\cdot f +g_1 \cdot g_2=0$ where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are defined like that:

$g_1(x,y)=f(x,y)$ for $x \leq y$ and $g_1(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for $x>y$.

$g_2(x,y)=f(x,y)$ for $x \geq y$ and $g_2(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for $x<y$.